# why would .load not work in IE8

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have this code,

```
    $(".delete").live("click", function () {
    alert("!");
    var self = $(this);
    var loadUrl = $(this).attr('href');
    var interestParents = self.parents('div:eq(4)').attr("id");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: loadUrl,
        data: "isAjax=1"
    }).done(function (msg) {
        self.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().fadeOut('fast', function () {
            $(this).remove();
        });
        //console.log($("#"+interestParents).load(site_url+"my_profile/interests " + "#" + interestParents).fadeIn('fast'));
        //$("#UL_" + msg + "items").load(site_url + "my_profile/interests " + "#UL_" + msg + "items").fadeIn('fast');
        $("#large_buttons").load(site_url + "my_profile #large_buttons > *").show();

    });
    return false;
});
```

and I cannot for life of me work out why the `.load` does not load the data into the large_buttons div, it definatly exists on the page, and it works in every other browser but IE8.

Comment: what version of jQuery you use?

Comment: F12 - open the NET tab, look for errors.

Comment: also check if IE8 is running in compatibility mode.

Comment: just a question, if you use `var self = $(this)`, than why you use in the next line `$(this)` again? and over and over?

Comment: You know that instead of `.parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent()` you can use `.closest([selector])` ?

Comment: You know that instead of `var loadUrl = $(this).attr('href');` is lighter to use `this.href;` ?

Comment: You know that as of jQuery v.1.7+ the method `.live()` is deprecated and replaced by `.on()` ?

Comment: Where is siteurl defined and what do you get from the load() call?

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure that the page you are "load"ing (my_profile) is valid HTML (no misplaced end tags, unclosed tags, etc). I had an issue like this with IE8 because the markup I was trying to load was invalid. Most browsers managed to interpret the bad markup, but IE8 failed.

An HTML [validator](http://validator.w3.org/) may help you.

Comment: The HTML gets returned though - I can see it in the reponse in my console.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this way:

```
$("#large_buttons").show().load(site_url + "my_profile #large_buttons > *");
```

although i am unable to see where is the site_url variable, if this is a type then you should use this

```
$("#large_buttons").show().load(loadUrl + "my_profile #large_buttons > *");
```